# Bitcoin-qt transaction not initiated by the wallet owner

Tags: transactions, wallet, bitcoin-core

I was just mining for some Dogecoins with Eobot and parallel I had BGFminer set on solo mining + 4 pools from eclipse.

The issue is that the moment the Eobot kicked in (it started on mining Dogecoins as they just started on increasing) I saw a notice of Bitcoin transaction, asap I opened the client to see it i found the following:

[image]

The best part is that I did not post my sending address anywhere nor iniciated this transaction (And seems I have this wallet since a week and this is the entire  amount that was stored there) so is it possible that i got some Trojan on my PC that somehow managed to process this transaction or similar.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hypothesis of a Trojan seems likely, unfortunately. Just be glad you didn't have more coins in that wallet.

You'll probably want to wipe and reinstall the computer in question.

Comment: Well , that's what i expected ...